# receive updates according my tags

Tags: support, questions, tag-watching

How can I receive updates from Stack Overflow, according to my favorite tags?

I tested the Android app Stack Remote, but I can't login with it.

Is there an app for Android that lets me know when a new question is posted in my favorite tags, or is there another method to do this?

Comment: thanks @Jim to correct my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every tag shows this on mouseover; you can either **subscribe** for updates via email or get updates via the [tag](/questions/tagged/tag)-specific RSS feed.

[image: rss]

Comment: Thanks, I did this yesterday